# Can I draw pictures if I cover them?

Tags: drawing

My dad used to say that I could draw people if I covered them.

Is that true?

Answer (score 2):

No this is not true, the drawing of people (or any other animate things like animals) is not allowed whether you cover them or not.  As it has been authentically narrated in regards to those who draw/paint such, that they will be in the hell fire, [Source](http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/18/170).

Comment: The quoted hadith has some contradictions. `Every painter will go to Hell`, a painter who draws scenaries is also a painter. Later it say `If you have to do it, draw pictures of trees and other inanimate things`. Seems like not all painters will go to hell as quoted in the initial part of the hadith.

Comment: @muslim1 There is no contradiction.  The obvious meaning of Painter in this Hadith, after Ibn Abbas further Explained, is obviously referring to all painters who paint animate beings like People and animals.  As for those who paint scenaries like trees etc, then they are not the ones whom are being talked about in the Hadith.

Comment: please include this is a sunni view answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you cover them in a form that they are not distinguished as people then the draw is a different draw.

Anyway according to Shia Islam drawing depends on if what you draw is used as objects of worship by other religions or not. Also depends on which scholar or Marja' you follow for Islamic laws.

> Drawing, painting or carving a living being is permissible. 
>   Similarly, making statues or sculptures of non-living things like
>   flowers or trees is permissible.
>
> Sculpting, painting or drawing of living or non-living things or
>   symbols that are used as objects of worship by other religions is not
>   allowed.  So making, buying or selling idols or religious symbols such
>   as a cross would not be permissible.

---

**References:**

[Business Moral Codes in Islam](http://www.islamic-laws.com/download/Business%20Moral%20Codes%20in%20Islam.doc)

[['Aalim Network QR] Painting, Drawing, Sculptures.](http://www.al-islam.org/organizations/AalimNetwork/msg00254.html)